# Firebase remoteConfig doesnt override in app default

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-remote-config

I hooked up a website to Firebase for its backend and I intend to change some elements value using the firebase remoteconfig. I installed and configured the firebase and Firebase remoteConfig and write the code to get the remoteConfig value I set in the firebase console.

when I console log the remoteConfig value, it logs an object with a “_source” and “_value” properties but the “source” property is still set as “default ” and the value property is still the in app value and not the remoteConfig value I set, so this means its not getting modified by the remoteConfig I set in the Firebase console??!
I also made sure I used the same parameter key both in my code and Firebase console. Please help me out someone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.